# Sort a 2D list by two fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Suppose I have a 2D list:

```
data = []
data.append([7, 12, 19, 'Type1', 'New'])
data.append([1, 2, 21, 'Type3', 'New'])
data.append([12, 7, 22, 'Type2', 'Active'])
data.append([3, 0, 22, 'Type3', 'Active'])
data.append([0, 1, 18, 'Type2', 'Closed'])
data.append([13, 11, 19, 'Type1', 'Closed'])
```

I would like to sort this 2d list by the fourth and fifth columns. I'd like column 4 to be sorted ascending, but column 5 to be in order of New, Active, Closed.

Desired 2d list:

```
[7, 12, 19, 'Type1', 'New'])
[13, 11, 19, 'Type1', 'Closed'])
[12, 7, 22, 'Type2', 'Active'])
[0, 1, 18, 'Type2', 'Closed'])
[1, 2, 21, 'Type3', 'New'])
[3, 0, 22, 'Type3', 'Active'])
```

This line gets me close, but not quite:

```
sortedData = sorted(data, key=lambda x:(x[3],x[4]))
```

Any suggestions on sorting by two fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a dictionary priority mapping and then use a `tuple` sort key:

```
priorities = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(['New', 'Active', 'Closed'])}

res = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x[3], priorities[x[4]]))

print(res)

[[7, 12, 19, 'Type1', 'New'],
 [13, 11, 19, 'Type1', 'Closed'],
 [12, 7, 22, 'Type2', 'Active'],
 [0, 1, 18, 'Type2', 'Closed'],
 [1, 2, 21, 'Type3', 'New'],
 [3, 0, 22, 'Type3', 'Active']]
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! I can't wrap my head around priorities[x[4]]. Mind explaining?

Comment: `priorities` is a dictionary, `x[4]` represents the last value in each sublist. so `priorities[x[4]]` looks up the this key in the dictionary `priorities`. So the result will be `0`, `1`, or `2`. `print(priorities)` if you want to see the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes a lot of sense now.